# How to get the path of the Currently opened file from eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin. I want to know the currently opened file's path name programmatically. It would be of great help anyone could help.

Thanks 
Partha

Answer (score 2):

You can use IWorkbenchPage.getActiveEditor or getEditors(), then you can 
ask the editors for their IEditorInput. If the editor is operating on 
an IFile (and there is no guarantee that it is), then you can cast 
IEditorInput to IFileEditorInput to get access to the file via 
IFileEditorInput.getFile().

Once you get IFile you can get path eaisly

References 
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/12808/